# Windows HAL dll cannot be used anymore

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, kernel

I ve got this weird problem.

For a long time I was running xp sp3 with /hal=halmacpi.dll switch in boot options. Everything fine.

I just booted to the "old" normal mode, without the switch. (I used the switch because I had problems with the usb driver, some of my usb ports didn't work, so the switch solved the problem.) 
During the visit in the old mode, I pluged a usb stick in a port that didn't worked properly; Windows tried to identify and "install" it, but no usb stick in explorer, just as expected. I just couldn't access the stick. 
So, I rebooted, to boot with the switch option, but while Windows was saving settings during shutdown, the shudown somehow hapenned very quick, and I heard a buzz in speakers. When Windows tried to boot with the switch, they stuck, nothing happend, just reboot loop. I can boot only in the old mode.

So now the /hal=halmacpi.dll cannot be used, although I replaced that dll in fear that it might became corrupted, but still the same problem.

Does anyone have any tiny idea on this?

Comment: What exactly does this switch do?  You say you can only boot without the switch is that because its not longer offered or because you added the option and it still didn't work?

Comment: This switch loads different hal dll. After the reboot, I tried to load Windows with the switch, but it didn't boot. It cannot boot with the switch nomore, I don't know why. I am sure that something became corrupted/altered durring the shutdown, perhaps in addition with the usb stick situation.

Comment: My understanding of the dll in question is that its very system specific.  What happens exactly when you attempt to boot with that switch?  Saying "it doesn't work" is not descriptive enough.

Comment: Windows dont boot. Black screen, then bios again

Comment: How about the safe mode switch in conjunction with the switch you want to use?

Comment: Ha! of course I tried it; still doesn't boot. Even with "start  with the latest settings" option.

Comment: This likely means your only real solution is to install Windows XP.  You really should determine the reason you cannot use USB devices without using this switch though.

Comment: Thats what I 'm trying to avoid. I really dont know why, but I had problems with usb sticks, and I saw in a forum disqusion (can't find it anymore, I have cleared the hsitory in browser) someone mentioning about the hal dll switch, so I tried it and the system was just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved  it. This way might also fix general startup/boot issues too, if it is the way.

I removed some unused device drivers from device manager, so thats what might did the trick. I also found from my saved xp "image" (the whole files in a rar file) the halmacpi.dll and I put it in windows/system 32. I am not sure if that did the trick becuse in the previous attempts I took the halmacpi.dll from the original disk.

Anyway, removing obsolete/unused devices is a good thing!